# Mongodb import csv File

Tags: mongodb, csv, import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE6A9.png) I am doing a mongoimport with the following command:
mongodbimport -d movies -c cust --type csv --file c:***.csv -- headerline

I get the message that 1190375 records were imported. I can see that the collection have been created when I show collections.

But when I go to the collection

```
use movies
use cust
db.cust.find()
```

Only Null is displayed.

Is there something I am doing wrong?
I am only using the evalution version, can that perhaps be the restriction

Comment: Are you sure *movie* database is the current database when open your mongo client?

Comment: the database is movies.

Comment: You can edit your question and click on image icon on the editor toolbar (or use Ctrl + G)

Comment: I have added the commands how I get to the certain collection on my question

Answer (score 0):

You are doing :

```
use movies use cust db.cust.find()
```

Basically, you are switching to `movies` database, then back to `cust` database. So `db.cust.find()` will look for `cust` collection in `cust` database.

Just do :

```
use movies;
db.cust.find();
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add your screen capture your commands change database to `cust` so your query try to find collection `cust` on database `cust` (not in `movie`).

When you open your mongo client you must use this commands:

```
use movies
db.cust.find()
```

**Note:** you don't need `use cust` to query *cust* collection.

Comment: ok thank you very much.I could see my collection now.I though I had to use  the collection also.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use "use cust" as you are already inside the db just use db.cust.find() after use movies .